# How to use PostgreSQL upper() function with a different locale?

Tags: postgresql, locale

I have a PostgreSQL database on a shared host and the result of using the `upper` function is different in my local database because of the locale setting.

Here is what I want, and have in my local environment:

```
SELECT version();
-- "PostgreSQL 8.4.16 on i386-apple-darwin10.8.0, compiled by GCC i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3), 64-bit"

SHOW LC_COLLATE;
-- "fr_FR.UTF-8"

SELECT upper('étienne');
-- "ÉTIENNE"
```

Here is what I have in the production environment:

```
SELECT version();
-- "PostgreSQL 9.0.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.3.real (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2, 64-bit"

SHOW LC_COLLATE;
-- "C"

SELECT upper('étienne');
-- éTIENNE
```

Now, because the production environment is in a shared host, I cannot change the locale due to the host policies. So, is there another way to have the expected result when using upper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you **cannot** override the collation (like demonstrated by other answers) in your versions 8.4 or 9.0. This [feature was introduced with Postgres **9.1**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html).

In earlier versions, you cannot change the collation chosen when the database was created. The `COLLATE` key word does not exist and you get an error if you try `SET LC_COLLATE = ...`:

```
ERROR: parameter "lc_collate" cannot be changed
```

You need a more current version to do that.

[-> SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1152)

Sorry, but you are out of luck.

Answer (score 5):

For 9.1 and up, you can just choose collation locally for the query.
Sadly, considering your version numbers, that would require an upgrade, so may or may not be helpful.

```
SELECT UPPER('étienne' COLLATE "C")      C_Collation,
       UPPER('étienne' COLLATE "fr_FR") FR_Collation;

C_Collation        FR_Collation
--------------------------------------
éTIENNE            ÉTIENNE
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1131).

Answer (score 1):

```
select upper('étienne') collate "fr_FR";
```