# Why UPPER function doesnt change lower case accent char

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

why `upper()` of lower case accent doesnt produce any changes

so my state name tranlate like this

```
upper('táchira') = 'TáCHIRA'
upper('guárico') = "GUáRICO"
```

I would like

```
'TÁCHIRA' and 'GUÁRICO'
OR 'TACHIRA' and 'GUARICO'
```

field `estado` is the state name

```
CREATE TABLE mapas.estadosven_region
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  geoid double precision,
  estado character varying(80),
  CONSTRAINT estadosven_region_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

Comment: I would suggest you start by looking at this link as it may be that your database locale is incorrect, or you may need to specify locale parameters elsewhere e.g. on your connection: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/locale.html

Comment: This may be an answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729640/how-to-use-postgresql-upper-function-with-a-different-locale